# Form with select and numbers ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I need to create a order scaffold that let me know the needs of our clients in a list of products and the units they want to order. 
I wouldn't like to create one order for every product, i would like to have the list of the products, and the option of say how much of this product the client will order. 
Any suggestions for this kind of form with ruby on rails and scaffold?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a scaffold of Order and model of OrderProduct.
Order will have simple order details and relation with user.
OrderProduct will have two associations order and product and it will also have units count.

Now for form you can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and for form you can use Add More button to allow user to add as many products as much they want.

Comment: Could you be a little more detailed in the explanation please? I have the scaffold order with this structure: 
Nombre Razon social Nit Direccion Telefono Nombre representante Persona contacto Pedido The field Pedido, would be your OrderProduct, so i must to create the model Product? Rails g Model Product, and then what do you sugest? Product and Units? I didn't undestood the form, could you explain me please? Thank you very much!

Comment: basically you can't store product details in order's table so there should be a bridge table between product and order where you can also store unit count too. About form you can use this fields_for(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) to specify fields of bridge table which would be product and units and when your form will submit it will be stored in order_products table with the help of accept_nested_attributes_for(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Haven't you created product scaffold before?

Comment: Then you should create a product scaffold first because if you haven't added any product in the system then how user will make order

Comment: Ok! and then how do i make the relations between tables? i have to modify a field in the pedidos table really?